# Nginx reverse-proxy returning internal IP instead of domain name

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

After creating certbot ssl for NGINX reverse proxy through the certbot plugin, my proxied site is redirecting to the internal IP of the web server instead of the FQDN.

Here's the reverse-proxy.conf:

```
***server {
    server_name mail.mycoolurl.com;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.13.13;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mycoolurl.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Cert$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mycoolurl.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Ce$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = mail.mycoolurl.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name mail.mycoolurl.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

So if I go to http://mail.mycoolurl.com, i get redirected to https://192.168.13.13, which the web browser can't hit whem they are out in the world.

Comment: It's most probably your backend server that is configured to redirect to the wrong URL.

Comment: First, you put your finger right on it.

Comment: So the reverse proxy is converting the request from FQDN to internal IP. That' correct except the server or the web server then continues the conversation as the IP (http://192.168.13.13) it was presented as the URL. So that's what the r-proxy is sending back to the requester.
Is the solution a header rewrite? or is that a new post as a separate question?

Comment: Usually this is solved by configuring the domain name in backend application settings. That is the most reliable way of configuring this. If you cannot find how to configure it, you can open a question for it.

Comment: OK, I'll take that to iRedMail. Problem has been identified if not resolved. thanks!